# Loop Through Column to find Match - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a VBA Command that goes through many cases in order to find a commission fee percentage. Starting off, I need to compare a ID to a list of Special IDs (Using one Integer, loop through a column of 30 integers). I also need to check to see if the 'komisija' value is greater than 40, which would then simply return 40.

```
Dim klienta_nr As Long
Dim ISIN As String
Dim Cena As Double
Dim Skaits As Double
Dim Komisija As Double

Set kSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("komisijas")

'Set variables equal to the cell data
  klienta_nr = Range("A2").Value
  ISIN = Range("E2").Value
  Cena = Range("H2").Value
  Skaits = Range("I2").Value


'First, have case for non-special klients
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(klienta_nr, kSheet.Range("A2:A40")) Then
      If Right(klienta_nr, 1) = 1 Or Right(klienta_nr, 1) = 8 Then
        Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.003
        End If
      If Right(klienta_nr, 1) = 7 Then
        Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.01
        End If
      If Komisija > 40 Then
        Range("K2").Value = Komisija
        End If
      Range("K2").Value = Komisija
End If

Range("K2").Value = Komisija
```

Comment: Is there a particular problem you're looking to solve? Is your code generating an error? Is it doing what you need it to do? I'm not sure what your question actually is.

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing? `Range(komisijas!A)`.

Comment: I'm trying to see if variable, klienta_nr, matches with an integer in a colum. As a Excel function, I would be using MATCH, but for VBA I'm not sure what to use.

Comment: Please don't overwrite questions with answers, or add [solved] to the title. I have rolled this back to the last thing that looked like a question. Please do add a self-answer below if you wish to help future readers, or accept an existing one, by clicking the adjacent green "tick" icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Application.Match function to compare variables. By doing so I was able to get the expected result I was looking for.

```
'Set variables equal to the cell data
klienta_nr = Range("A2").Value
ISIN = Range("E2").Value
Cena = Range("H2").Value
Skaits = Range("I2").Value
vk = Range("B2").Value

    If Not Application.Match(klienta_nr, kSheet.Range("A2:A100")) Then
      'IP2, 0.03% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
         If Right(vk, 1) = 1 Or Right(vk, 1) = 8 Then
            Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.003
            Range("K2").Value = Komisija
            End If
      'IP1, 0.1% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
        If Right(vk, 1) = 7 Then
            Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.01
            Range("K2").Value = Komisija
            End If
        'Komisija MAX is 40, so anything >=40 equals 40
        If Komisija >= 40 Then
            Range("K2").Value = 40
            End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right you must do this:

```
for each k in range("komisijas")
 If klienta_nr = k.value Then
   If Right(klienta_nr, 1) = 1 Or Right(klienta_nr, 1) = 8 Then
     Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.003
   If Right(klienta_nr, 1) = 7 Then
     Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.01
   End If
   If Komisija > 40 Then
     Range("D4").Value = 40
   End If
     Range("D4").Value = Komisija
 End If
next
```

This code is not tested.

Comment: Hi Fernando, how does the "For Each K In komisijas" work, I did not get it, me not a VBA expert

Comment: Sorry, i updated to Range("komisijas"). I understood komisijas is a named range. I'm right?

Comment: Not quite what I was trying to get at, but I updated my code above. Still not working, but might give you an idea of where I'm trying to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim var as Variant
var = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(klienta_nr, kSheet.Range("A2:A17"))
If Not iserror(var) Then
```